# Powershell Get-Content with Wait flag and IOErrors

Tags: powershell, logging, ioerror

I have a PowerShell script that spawns x number of other PowerShell scripts in a Fire-And-Forget way.

In order to keep track of the progress of all the scripts that I just start, I create a temp file, where I have all of them write log messages in json format to report progress.

In the parent script I then monitor that log file using `Get-Content -Wait`. Whenever I receive a line in the log file, I parse the json and update an array of objects that I then display using `Format-Table`. That way I can see how far the different scripts are in their process and if they fail at a specific step. That works well... almost.

I keep running into IOErrors because so many scripts are accessing the log file, and when that happens the script just aborts and I lose all information on what is going on.

I would be able to live with the spawned scripts running into an IOError because they just continue and then I just catch the next message. I can live with some messages getting lost as this is not an audit log, but just a progress log.

But when the script that tails the log crashes then I lose insight.

I have tried to wrap this in a Try/Catch but that doesn't help. I have tried setting `-ErrorAction Stop` inside the Try/Catch but that still doesn't catch the error.

My script that reads looks like this:

```
function WatchLogFile($statusFile)
{
    Write-Host "Tailing statusfile: $($statusFile)"
    Write-Host "Press CTRL-C to end."
    Write-Host ""
    Try {
    Get-Content $statusFile -Force -Wait | 
        ForEach { 
            $logMsg = $_ | ConvertFrom-JSON
            #Update status on step for specific service
            $svc = $services | Where-Object {$_.Service -eq $logMsg.Service}
            $svc.psobject.properties[$logMsg.step].value = $logMsg.status

            Clear-Host
            $services | Format-Table -Property Service,Old,New,CleanRepo,NuGet,Analyzers,CleanImports,Build,Invoke,Done,LastFailure
        } -ErrorAction Stop
    } Catch {
        WatchLogFile $statusFile
    }
}
```

And updates are written like this in the spawned scripts

```
Add-Content $statusFile $jsonLogMessage
```

Is there an easy way to add retries or how can I make sure my script survives file locks?

Comment: Why are you not using Jobs?

Comment: I don't know... why am I not using jobs? This script is not running on a server, but on a desktop. I haven't used PowerShell jobs before, so wasn't aware that might be a way to do this. Is there anything in particular about Jobs that I should be looking at in this respect?

Comment: it's a topic I think will help you.  Type:     PS:> help about_jobs

Comment: It seems that I cannot get running updates from a job. I can only get the output when it is finished. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChiliYago pointed out I should use jobs. So that is what I have done now. I had to figure out how to get the output as it arrived from the many scripts.

So I did added all my jobs to an array of jobs and and monitored them like this. Beware that you can receive multiple lines if your script has had multiple outputs since you invoked `Receive-Job`. Be sure to use `Write-Output` from the scripts you execute as jobs.

```
$jobs=@()
foreach ($script in $scripts)
{
    $sb = [scriptblock]::create("$script $(&{$args} @jobArgs)")
    $jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb
}

while ($hasRunningJobs -gt 0)
{
    $runningJobs = $jobs | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"} | measure
    $hasRunningJobs = $runningJobs.Count

    foreach ($job in $jobs)
    {
        $outvar = Receive-Job -Job $job
        if ($outvar)
        {
            $outvar -split "`n" | %{ UpdateStatusTable $_} 
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "All scripts done."
```